# SqlXml throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql, race-condition, sqlxml, read-uncommitted

I have a trouble. :(

MS SQL Server 2016 13.0.15900.1
.NET Framework 4.5.2

- There is a table with large xml fields (> 1 mb)
- A terrible procedure which read, change and update [xmlField] with(out) XPath
- The procedure selects [xmlField] from [myTable] where [id] = @id
- And a dynamic SQL-request with (readuncommitted, nolock).

The terrible procedure and the dynamic request working fine.
The procedure which selects [xmlField] leads to NullReferenceException in the System.Data.dll

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at System.Xml.XmlSqlBinaryReader.ScanAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlSqlBinaryReader.ImplReadElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlSqlBinaryReader.ReadDoc()
   at System.Xml.XmlSqlBinaryReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml.get_Value()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteExecuteScalar(SqlDataReader ds, Boolean returnSqlValue)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

What the hell is going on and how I can avoid it?

Probably, we read only a part of XML, which did not have time to enroll to the end, which leads to corrupt of the xml-document. But how then can this be circumvented? Working with XML as a string?

Comment: With readuncommited you can read damaged xml blob, which is probably what happens here, so just use higher isolation level?

Comment: @Evk With readuncommited - yes. But as I say I was got a corrupted xml via stored procedure **without** this modificator.